# conditional replacement of <br> tags that considers multi and single tag scenarios

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a php function that will treat a string considering instances of single and multiple `<br>` tags as unique treatments. I'd like it to take any instances where there are multiple `<br>` tags e.g. (`<br><br>`, or `<br><br><br>` or `<br><br><br><br>` etc) and replace with a single snippet of `</p><p>`, BUT still allow single instances of a `<br>` tag to go unaltered. So as an example:

```
//INPUT STRING:
"<p>A yellow dog <br> An orange fox <br><br> A purple bird <br><br><br> A red rooster</p>"
//OUTPUT STRING:
"<p>A yellow dog <br> An orange fox </p><p> A purple bird </p><p> A red rooster</p>"
```

Appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`preg_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

```
$input_lines="<p>A yellow dog <br> An orange fox <br><br> A purple bird <br><br><br> A red rooster</p>";
preg_replace("/(<br>){2}/", "<\p><p>", $input_lines);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/104949)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**

```
<p>A yellow dog <br> An orange fox <\p><p> A purple bird <\p><p><br> A red rooster</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that replaces the single instances of the <br> tag also. This is undesired. I'd like to replace all multi-instances BUT leave any single instances of the <br> tag. Please refer to my initial example.

Comment: i missed the comma in my regex (<br>{2,})

Comment: Brilliant. Is there a way to modify this to account for br tags with slashes also e.g. <br/>, as opposed to just <br> ...?

Comment: use the alternation like this (<br>|<br\/>){2,}

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
$str = "<p>A yellow dog <br> An orange fox <br><br><br> A purple bird <br><br> A red rooster</p>";
$res = preg_replace("/(<br>){2,}/", "<p></p>", $str);
print_r("<pre>".htmlentities($res)."</pre>");
//OUTPUT- <p>A yellow dog <br> An orange fox <p></p> A purple bird <p></p> A red rooster</p>
```